# Status of the SBP-M1 review on Kylin Network Node implementation

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node, oracles

Kylin network is waiting on a final review of their node implementation: https://github.com/Kylin-Network/kylin-collator/pull/127
Changes have been applied (https://github.com/Kylin-Network/kylin-collator/pull/127/files) but no action from SBP after 5 december 2022.
What is the reason the review is not happening on this node implementation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't fit into the Substrate SE. This is a question about the builder program and not about any technical details.

Comment: Can you advise me where to ask these kind of questions?

Comment: Get in contact with the SBP team. SE is for technical questions.